# How do I load a file from FileCabinet in SuiteScript

Tags: csv, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want to import a csv file using a saved csv import in suitescript.
For this I'm testing my code in the script debugger.

I successfully did this in Suitescript 1.0 like this:

```js
var import1 = nlapiCreateCSVImport(); 
import1.setMapping('custimport_test_import'); 
import1.setPrimaryFile(nlapiLoadFile(252)); 
nlapiSubmitCSVImport(import1);
```

Now i tried it in Suitescript 2.0 like this:

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
var func = require(["N/task", "N/file"], function(task, file) {
  var csv = file.load({ id: 252 });

  var mrTask = task.create({
    taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT,
    importFile: csv,
    mappingId: "custimport_test_import"
  });

  mrTask.submit();
});

func();
```

The Error i get is TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (SYSTEM_LIBS$debugger.sys#2396)

How can i achive what I did with the 1.0 Script with 2.0 Script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It somehow worked with a slightly different approach:

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */
var func = require(["N/task", "N/file"], function(task, file) {
  var scriptTask = task.create({ taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT });
  scriptTask.mappingId = "custimport_test_import";
  var f = file.load("SuiteScripts/test.csv");
  scriptTask.importFile = f;
  var csvImportTaskId = scriptTask.submit();
});

func();
```

The debugger still returned the error described above, but the record was created in netsuite.